# Tomcat 8 Apparently Running (Says Eclipse) 404 Error in Browser

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, localhost, tomcat7, tomcat8

The title kind of says it all. I'm using tomcat 8 and Eclipse Luna. I start my tomcat instance from within Eclipse and then I'm able view it at localhost:8080. I've been using this for a few months now, everything ran smoothly and the people of dev-land we're happy folk.

But then... it happened. All of a sudden it just stopped working. When I now run Tomcat from Eclipse, Eclipse still says that it's running, and how marvelously it started up. But when I view it in my browser I get a big 404 f-u .

I've tried re installing Tomcat (twice). I've even tried Tomcat 7. Same story the whole time. What has happened??

Comment: Ah.. I see what my problem was. I solved it by switching to Intelij

Comment: You should try using build-in browser in Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Tried that as well, but had the same issue